# URL string from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `foreach` loop running all all my records from the database and displaying them in a list on a page. What I'm now trying to do is have a clickable button that will load another page that will show just the information from that list item.

So its lists all records with a view button on each one, so when you click the view button it will load the 2nd view and just display the item clicked, if that makes sense

The first view is list items:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 225px;">
            <?php foreach ($posts as $webstore): ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center thumbnail1234">
                        <?php foreach($webstore['images'] as $image) : ?>
       <img class="img-responsive"  src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <h3><?php echo $webstore['title']; ?></h3> 
                        <p>Date Added: <?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($webstore['created'])) ?></p>
                         <hr>
<a href="<?= site_url("Webstore/webstore_large/['id']"); ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary center-block">View</a>                    

                        <hr>
                    </div>
```

Which would then link to this view:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php foreach ($posts as $webstore): ?>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <?php foreach ($webstore['images'] as $image) : ?>
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3><?php echo $webstore['title']; ?></h3> 
                        <p>Date Added: <?php echo date('d-m-y', strtotime($webstore['created'])) ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $webstore['content']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I'm hoping to use this controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Webstore extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("post");
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper("url");


}
public function index() {
    $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->get_webstore($limit=null, $offset=null); // calling Post model method getPosts()
    $this->data['page_title'] = 'Store';
    $this->layout("pages/webstore", $this->data);
}

function webstore_large() {
    $this->db->select['id'];       
    $this->layout("pages/webstore_page");
}

}
```

Any help here would be great.

Comment: What is your *question*? We need to know what is specifically wrong - describe the problem in-depth, don't just slap us with some code.

Comment: sorry added a little more info

Comment: Yes, you added a little more info on what you *want* it to do, but specifically are you hitting a roadblock with that it that it doesn't already do that?

Comment: sorry again , so my question is almost where to start , i have used the example below and still struggling, im in a bit of a bind as im not a php dev and have a basic level of understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give href to a tag

```
<a href="<?= base_url("Webstore/view/$webstore['id']") ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary center-block">View</a>
```

Considering `id` is an unique column in your table.

In `webstore controller`,

```
function view($id) {
   //write login to fetch `$id`'s data from database.

   //load the 2nd view here.

}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks, right i have added the href and called the view in the controller   and gone for this     $this->data['posts'] = $this->post->id();
 im a front end dev with very limited knowleage of PHP so sorry if i seem to come across a little dumb lol